# use last dimension of 3D numpy matrix as arguments of function

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, multiprocessing

context:
I have a data frame with a list of data. that I need to compare between each other:

```
x_test
0    [0.9948399033268663, 0.9948399033268663, 0.995...
1    [1.0005639107922013, 1.00041937494038, 1.00020...
2    [0.9975316557982873, 0.9975316557982873, 0.997...
Name: cycle_info_scaled, dtype: object
```

To do the computation I'm using the following function that takes 2 list as arguments to compare:

```
def vec_compute_distance(*args):
    args = args[0]
    if len(args) != 2:
        print(f"args lens is {len(args)}, Should take 2 values")
        return 0
    else:
        return _ucrdtw.ucrdtw(args[0], args[1], 0.05, False)[1]
```

I have create a 3d matrix out of the Series to map the function the function:

```
grid_test = np.asarray(np.meshgrid(x_test, x_test)).T
```

where ***grid_test*** shape is:

```
grid_test.shape
(3, 3, 2)
```

I'm trying to map the function to the (3x3) matrix using the last dimension (2 elements) as the arguments of the function.
I have tried this:

```
for i in range(grid_test.shape[0]):
    for j in range(grid_test.shape[1]):
        grid_test[i,j] = vec_compute_distance(grid_test[i,j])
```

but it's returning the following ***error***:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [26], in <cell line: 3>()
      2 grid_test = np.asarray(np.meshgrid(x_test, x_test)).T
      3 for i in range(grid_test.shape[0]):
----> 4     grid_test[i] = list(map(vec_compute_distance, grid_test[i]))

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3) into shape (3,2)
```

PD:
This code already does it but I need to change it to work with map to use ***multiprocessing*** because it's a big amount of data to process:

```
for i in range(grid_test.shape[0]):
    for j in range(grid_test.shape[1]):
        grid_test[i,j] = vec_compute_distance(grid_test[i,j])
```

Can you advised me on how to resolve the issue?
Thanks!

Comment: Reminder that using multiprocessing will make copies of the arguments to map to send them to different processes. So if the data is big then you probably don't want to use multiprocessing (unless you use shared memory).

Comment: `grid_test[i]` is (3,2) shape.  Do you understand why?  The error says the RHS is a list of 3 items.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @Charchit, thanks for the advice, according to this document: https://medium.datadriveninvestor.com/python-multiprocessing-pool-vs-process-comparative-analysis-6c03c5b54eec,  "As we have seen, the Process allocates all the tasks in memory and Pool allocates only executing processes in memory, so when the task numbers is large, we can use Pool and when the task number is small, we can use Process class.", Is that right?

Comment: @hpaulj I think because I'm iterating over one of the dimensions (3) and trying to map to the others (3,2).

Comment: @josseossa I can't vouch for that since I haven't done the tests myself, but it is largely irrelevant to your case anyway. What I meant was that your data will have to be pickled and sent to another process for it to have access to the same data. This pickling creates a copy of the said data. So if you were to create 5 processes to make this task faster, then there will be 5 copies created of the same data. Moreover, the pickling and unpickling will take time too and you may end up actually having slower performance when using multiprocessing.